# Intersection & Union of ∅ & P{∅}

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I've been asked to find the intersection & union of the empty set, and the power set of the empty set. Is this correct?

Intersection: ∅
Union: {∅,{∅}}

Comment: Is the union you have written supposed to be $P(\varnothing)$?  It is actually $P(P(\varnothing))$.

Comment: Fun fact: $\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ is how you [derive the natural numbers from set theoretic constructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Set-theoretic_models).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intersection is correct.

For any set $A$, what is the union $A\cup\emptyset$?

Comment: It is just set A correct? So that would make the union just {∅}?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not. Your intersection is correct.

The power set of the empty set is just $\{ \emptyset \}$. Now, unioning the empty set with anything will have no effect, so the union is again just $\{ \emptyset \}$.

Comment: You're welcome. If it helps, you can think of the empty set as the "identity" of set unions, much as $0$ is the identity of addition of real numbers.

Comment: It more than helps.  In the language of Boolean algebras, a field of sets calls the empty set $0$.